# Compile FLA to SWF using AIR SDK 3.1 and ADT for (swf-version=14) possible?

Tags: ios5, air, flash-cs5, adt, air-native-extension

Is it possible to use the ADT command line to directly compile an .fla file into an .swf file? Context: I have an app created in Flash Pro CS55 (6 months worth of work), but now found Adobe has dropped Flash Pro in favor of Flash Builder or Flex. I have some native extensions I want to use for iOS, but they require Air 3.1 to compile (swf-version=14) i.e. using the MessageUI framework in a static .a library for an Air app. Flash Pro CS55's top end limit seems to be swf-version=13 (Flash 11). Because of heavy investment in time and energy into our Air app in Flash Pro, it's not feasible to convert to Flex by end of week. I tried creating an .swc file, and taking the library.swf from that, but alas, a catch-22, Flash Pro CS55 only compiles to swf-version=13.

Is there any way to either (a) directly compile my root .swf file (from the .fla file) using a command line (so I can use ADT from Air 3.1 SDK) or (b) some way I can marry a native extension I've found I can use on GitHub which is swf-version=14? Again, my issue is that I have to use Air 3.1 since only it supports iOS5.

Any thoughts, suggestions, comments are highly appreciated (including if it's not possible to do what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can update Flash CS 5.5 to use AIR 3.1 - follow this manual http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/908/cpsid_90810.html
   Set "version" to 14.
2. AIR 3.1 requires iOS 4, not iOS 5. iOS 5 is required when you link with iOS frameworks introduced in iOS 5 (Twitter and few others)
3. You can use your root .swf file in Flex / Mobile AS AIR app, but no code will be imported.
   External swf files in mobile AIR applications can only contain assets (sounds, animations, etc.). Apple does not allow importing code to application at runtime.
4. I've written a tutorial on native iOS extensions for Adobe AIR - maybe you'll find it useful https://flashsimulations.com/2011/11/30/ios-native-extension-for-adobe-air-in-app-mail-composer/